# sort strings according to the highest

Tags: groovy

can I combine below closures into one or do this in a more functional and elegant way in groovy. I am using the sortMethod in some other places( for testing purpose)  too.

for eg : countAndMap should take 
`["a b c a  a c" , "b b c"]` and return`[x1 : [a:3,c:2,b:1] , x2 : [b:2,c:1]]`

```
def countAndMap(List<String> stringList) {
    stringList.withIndex().collect { String s, Integer i -> [(num.call(i)): count.call(s)] }
}


Closure count = {sortMethod.call(it.split().countBy {it}) }

Closure sortMethod = { it.sort { x, y -> x.value <=> y.value } }

Closure num  = { "x ${it + 1}".toString()}
```

there are no errors but I wonder if it's possible to do it in a more functional way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "more functional", but you could use a fold operation (called inject in groovy):

```
list = ["a b c a  a c" , "b b c"]
def createSortedHistogram(String toCount) {
    toCount
      .split() // Create list of words
      .inject([:]){ acc, word -> acc[word] = 1 + (acc[word] ?: 0);acc} // create histogram
      .sort{-it.value} // sort histogram map by value desc
}

def countAndMap(List<String> list) {
    list.withIndex().collectEntries{ sublist, i -> ["x ${i+1}": createSortedHistogram(sublist)] }
}
countAndMap(list)
```

I think the most interesting part is the `inject` method.
This solution uses the initial value `[:]` in order to use a map as result. In each iteration the `inject` operation either adds a new entry with value 1 to the map (if the word/key does not exist in the map) or increases the value of the word/key if it is already present in the map.

See the `inject` definition from [`Collections`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) GroovyDoc.

> `public Object inject(Object initialValue, Closure closure)` - Iterates through the given Collection, passing in the initial value to the 2-arg closure along with the first item. The result is passed back (injected) into the closure along with the second item. The new result is injected back into the closure along with the third item and so on until the entire collection has been used. Also known as foldLeft or reduce in functional parlance.